# Dual space basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I have three vectors, with unit normals, that form the basis of a coordinate system, these are

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{a}_{1} &= [a_{11},\,a_{12},\,0] \,, \\ 
\boldsymbol{a}_{2} &= [a_{21},\,a_{22},\,0] \,, \text{and} \\
\boldsymbol{a}_{3} &= [0,\,0,\,1] \,.
\end{align}

How do I determine the basis and basis vectors $\boldsymbol{a}^{1},\,\boldsymbol{a}^{2},\,\boldsymbol{a}^{3}$ of the adjoint space which is dual to the original space?

Further, how do I verify that the spaces are in fact dual?

(PS: I think it should satisfy $\left<\boldsymbol{a}_{i},\,\boldsymbol{a}^{j}\right>=\delta_{i}^{j}$ but I am not certain.)

Comment: Your PS is exactly correct, and you should use this to find the dual basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Do an Ansatz like
$$\boldsymbol{a}^1=P\varepsilon^1+Q\varepsilon^2+R\varepsilon^3,$$
where $\langle\varepsilon^i,e_j\rangle=\delta^i_j$, to set a linear system of equations
$$1=\langle \boldsymbol{a}^1,\boldsymbol{a}_1\rangle$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=\langle P\varepsilon^1+Q\varepsilon^2+R\varepsilon^3,a_{11}e_1+a_{12}e_2\rangle,$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad=Pa_{11}+Qa_{12},$$

$$0=\langle \boldsymbol{a}^1,\boldsymbol{a}_2\rangle$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=\langle P\varepsilon^1+Q\varepsilon^2+R\varepsilon^3,a_{21}e_1+a_{22}e_2\rangle,$$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad=Pa_{21}+Qa_{22},$$

$$0=\langle \boldsymbol{a}^1, \boldsymbol{a}_3\rangle,$$
$$\qquad=R.$$

...etc.

Comment: I'm a little confused by this.. If a^1=[P, Q, R] and a_1=[a_11, a_12, 0] should <a^1, a_1> not equal P*a_11 + Q*a_12 rather than P*a_11 + Q*a_21? Similarly, should  <a^1, a_2> not equal P*a_21 + Q*a_22 rather than P*a_12 + Q*a_22?

Comment: you are right, let me correct

Comment: So, this first part can be formulated as $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}P\\Q\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right],$$ which implies $$P=\dfrac{a_{22}}{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}},$$ $$Q=\dfrac{-a_{21}}{a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}},$$ and $$R=0.$$

Comment: thanks! to the good understander, little key formulas, Salutations.